# Is there any automated conversion from Go to Python?

Tags: python, go

Is there any program to automatically convert Go source code to Python source code?

Comment: Any reason why you need this?

Comment: Thanks, but we're not that unimaginative. Why do you need to convert Go code to Python code?

Comment: I need use of a library written in Go, in a Python application.

Comment: @Nathanael Then you question should be: Is there any way to call a Go library from Python? Which has a very different answer. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: I then need to adapt the library, making minor adjustments in places - so it would be best for me if I could have Python source code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that you'll find a way to do such a conversion with output that is actually useful. Go is very new, and if anything it would make more sense for someone to convert the other way around.

Comment: There's not even a (useful) converter between any two mature, well-known language very similar to each other. Because it's hard - not interesting-puzzle-hard, really-really-impractical-hard.

Comment: @delnan One could consider some decompilers to be examples of successful "converters".

Comment: And then we'd have to count compilers (to bytecode or native vode) as well. Clearly, neither is relevant here. Also note the "(useful)" part - decompiler output is nearly useless, as identifiers are stripped (exception I know: the .NET reflector) and usually non-idiomatic.

Comment: I think this is formally a correct answer (question: "is there", answer: "it's unlikely"); this is also the answer that I consider semantically correct, so +1.

Comment: @delnan But it does show that it isn't necessarily really-really-impractical-hard. I also just thought of a language-language compiler: HipHop, which compiles (a subset of) PHP into C++.

Comment: There's a difference between "compile" (so it runs, although it may be very messy etc.) and "convert" (so the result can be used in the future). I expect a converter to give a result I can check into source control and maintain.

Comment: @delnan Depends on definitions, but I agree with yours now that you say it.

Comment: @marcog PHP is, in a lot of ways, very similar to C++ (object-oriented syntax is similar, same operators, same basic syntax). Another good example would be GWT, which converts Java to Javascript (again, two very similar languages). It's not easy to convert two vastly different languages like Go and Python or Perl and C.

Comment: @Rafe Agreed, but that is what @delnan said doesn't exist (emphasis mine): "There's not even a (useful) converter between any two mature, well-known language *very* *similar* *to* *each* *other*."

Comment: @Rafe: NO, neither PHP and C++ nor Javascript and Java are similar. For starters: (1) Completely different type systems (dynamic vs. static) (2) lots of dynamic magic (implicit coversions, etc) and in case of JS you have (3) prototypes vs classes and (4) closures vs well, nothing. Only Syntax is similar, but syntax doesn't exist beyond the parser (and the parser is only a very small part of the ).

Comment: For a converter to be useful to me, it would need to convert Go source code into Python source code. It wouldn't have to be neat - I could refactor it manually into nicer idiom-compliant python code.